Asymptotic expansion with singularity subtraction
I am studying a set of lecture notes on the asymptotic expansion of integrals in the case of a removable singularity. While filling in some missing details and fixing some typos, I encountered some questions related to an exercise.
Part 1
Consider the following integral for $\epsilon \to 0$
$$ 
F(\epsilon) = \int_{0}^\pi \frac{\cos(x)}{\sqrt{x^2 + \epsilon^2}} \mathrm{d}x
$$
The derivation of the first two terms of the expansion proceeds as follows:
$$
F(\epsilon) = -\underbrace{\int_{0}^\pi \frac{1 - \cos(x)}{\sqrt{x^2 + \epsilon^2}} \mathrm{d}x}_{A} + \underbrace{\int_{0}^\pi \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + \epsilon^2}} \mathrm{d}x}_{B}
$$
For $B$, we have
$$
B = -\frac{1}{2} \log \left(\frac{2 \pi  \left(\pi -\sqrt{\epsilon ^2+\pi ^2}\right)}{\epsilon ^2}+1\right) = -\frac{1}{2} \log \left(\frac{\epsilon ^2}{4 \pi ^2}\right)+\frac{\epsilon ^2}{4 \pi ^2}+O\left(\epsilon ^3\right)
$$
For $A$, using Taylor's theorem
$$
1 - \cos(x) = x^2 + R_4(x)
$$
where there exists $C>0$ such that $|R_4(x)| \leq C x^4$  for every $x \in [0,\pi]$. Therefore $A$ is bounded (though it might be overkill here), we can exchange the integral with the limit and obtain:
$$
A \sim \int_0^\pi \frac{1 - \cos(x)}{x} \mathrm{d}x
$$
In conclusion
$$
F(\epsilon) \sim  -\frac{1}{2} \log \left(\frac{\epsilon ^2}{4 \pi ^2}\right) \sim  \log \left(\frac{1}{\epsilon}\right)
$$

Question 1: Is my derivation correct?

Part 2
Next, an exercise asks to generalize the above to the following integral:
$$
G(\epsilon) = \int_{0}^1 \frac{f(x)}{\sqrt{x^2 + \epsilon^2}} \mathrm{d} x 
$$
The simplest way to generalize the above is by assuming that $f(x) = f_0 + f_1(x)$ where $f_1(x) = O(x^\gamma)$ for some $\gamma>0$. Then
$$
G(\epsilon) = \underbrace{\int_{0}^1 \frac{f_1(x)}{\sqrt{x^2 + \epsilon^2}} \mathrm{d}x}_{A} + \underbrace{\int_{0}^1 \frac{f_0}{\sqrt{x^2 + \epsilon^2}} \mathrm{d}x}_{B}
$$
where again $A = O(1)$.

Question 2: I have done some numerical simulations (see below), and it seems that $f_1(x) = o(1)$ is enough to show that $G(\epsilon) \sim \log(1/\epsilon)$. Is this true? How can it be proved?

Edit
After Gary's comment, below are some numerical experiments
Some experiments taking $f_0 = 1$ and $f_1(x) \in  \{ -x^2, -\log(1+x), - 1/\log(x) \}$. For visualization I have plotted $G(1/z)$ where $z \to \infty$.


Have you tried $f_1(x)=\frac{1}{\log x}$?

@Gary Yes, I have added the plot. Could it be that the convergence to $log(1/\epsilon)$ is extremely slow?
